# Какие есть современные библиотеки под WPF.NET удобные для отображения электро сигналов?

Tags: wpf, .net, библиотеки, графики

Нужны функции:

1. зуминг, движение поля мышкой, движение графиков друг от друга мышкой и т.п.
2. делать "дрэг" - рисовать прямоугольник мышкой с разными целями - как для зума, так и чтобы создать "коридор" поверх графика, чтобы понять, попадает ли он в коридор или задевает потолок\пол.
3. задавать вертикальные линии , двигать и смотреть их пересечения с отдельными графиками либо проверять что в данной точке есть\нету пересечения в заданной окрестности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OxyPlot и ZedGraph имеют неплохие функции, частично покрывающие мои потребности. ZG более быстрый, зато для OP проще найти примеры. И функционал как-то лучше заработал под эти задачи.
Документация для обоих слабая.